# OpenStreetMap API How to get node id where natural=peak?

Tags: api, openstreetmap

I'm trying to access to the osm database...
What I want to do is to get the list of all the mountains in Italy.
The method I wont to emulate is a kind of SELECT WHERE natural=peak
But I don't know what's the best way to do this with APIs.
Can someone help me?

Really thank you so much ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API). You can make queries exactly [as you mentionned](http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/f4c)